# ubuntu 20.04 slow boot with time of 2-3 min approx

Tags: boot

i have installed ubuntu 20.04 lts on my laptop which is having an i7 9th gen cpu with 16 gb of ram. But the boot s very slow takes 2-3 min. Can anybody help me to resolve this?

this is the output of systemd-analyze blame command:
50.020s plymouth-quit-wait.service
25.936s man-db.service
20.932s snapd.service
20.105s apt-daily-upgrade.service
19.116s systemd-journal-flush.service
17.071s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.753s gpu-manager.service
13.553s udisks2.service
13.362s dev-sda6.device
10.847s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 9.808s accounts-daemon.service
 7.885s dev-loop4.device
 7.688s dev-loop9.device
 7.478s dev-loop19.device
 7.374s dev-loop15.device
 7.159s dev-loop17.device
 7.030s logrotate.service
 6.893s polkit.service
 6.878s avahi-daemon.service
 6.872s bluetooth.service
 6.869s NetworkManager.service
 6.386s apport-autoreport.service
 6.302s dev-loop13.device
lines 1-23

Comment: You should add the output of `systemd-analyze blame` to your question. (Edit question and include the output of the command, do not post as a comment). Also, a more significant information than CPU and RAM is the disc drive you are using, as this is usually the bottleneck.